# JSON.Parse: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script

In a Google Sheets script, I'm trying to JSON.Parse() a file. As it's 55Mb and 1.7M lines, I extracted a small snippet which is posted below. It returns the error "Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0".

I've checked the file in multiple places:

[**JSONLint**](https://jsonlint.com/): "valid JSON"
[**JSON To CSV**](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm) : converts it to CSV OK
**Notepad++** : recognises it, collapses/uncollapses correctly, etc
**JSTool Plugin** : minimises it, formats it - all OK

I'm unable to find anything to suggest it is not a valid JSON file - except JSON.Parse() ! I've searched extensively for error reasons, but nothing appears to apply. If anyone has a suggestion I'd appreciate it.

```
{
  "current_leg": 0,
  "distance_to_leader": 0,
  "rank": 0,
  "legInterp": {
    "valHistory": [
      [
        0,
        62084.53
      ],
      [
        1,
        62409.83
      ],
      [
        2,
        62669.17
      ],
      [
        3,
        62897.72
      ]
    ],
    "logging": false,
    "loggingPrefix": "",
    "timeoutSecs": 0,
    "mintime": 62084.53,
    "maxtime": 63992.76,
    "currentIdx": 0
  },
  "foilMoveTime": 2,
  "boatId": 32895,
  "teamId": 1
}
```

[Edit] Adding the Google Sheets Script I'm using:

```
function c_JSON() {
//  filename = 'boat1.json'; // 55 Mb file...
  filename = 'boat1_part.json'; // cut down version

  // define a file iterator
  // that will iterate through all files with the filename
  var iter = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  
  // iterate through all the files named filename
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    
    // define a File object variable and set the Media Tyep
    var file = iter.next();
//    var boatJSON = file.getAs('application/json')
    var boatPartJSON = file.getAs('application/json')
    
    // log the contents of the file
    //Logger.log(jsonFile.getDataAsString()); // ah, no, not for a 55Mb file!
    Logger.log(boatPartJSON.getDataAsString());
  
  }
  
//  var boatObject = JSON.parse(boatJSON); // <<<<<< SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0
  var boatObject = JSON.parse(boatPartJSON); // <<<<<< SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 again!
  
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Which `JSON.Parse()`? What framework/language/API are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Sheets Script (GAS?). Should I post the function as well?

Comment: It probably can't hurt :) FWIW, "Unexpected token B in JSON **at position 0**" sounds like perhaps the file has a preamble or some metadata that shouldn't be there (like `Body: {"actual":"Valid Json"}` for example),

Comment: Yes, that was the general gist of everything I found re this error - but surely it would show up in a text editor?  Function uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse() accepts a string parameter.

I tried your code and came up with a solution that is working fine on my end. Please see code below:

```
function c_JSON() {
//  filename = 'boat1.json'; // 55 Mb file...
  filename = 'boat1_part.json'; // cut down version

  // define a file iterator
  // that will iterate through all files with the filename
  var iter = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  
  // iterate through all the files named filename
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    
    // define a File object variable and set the Media Tyep
    var file = iter.next();
//    var boatJSON = file.getAs('application/json')
    var boatPartJSON = file.getAs('application/json')
    
    // log the contents of the file
    //Logger.log(jsonFile.getDataAsString()); // ah, no, not for a 55Mb file!
    Logger.log(boatPartJSON.getDataAsString());
  
  }
  
//  var boatObject = JSON.parse(boatJSON); // <<<<<< SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0
  var boatObject = JSON.parse(boatPartJSON.getDataAsString()); // <<<<<< SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 again!
  
  return true;
}
```

The only difference is the line where JSON.parse() happens. You should try getting the data as string first and before using JSON.parse().

Comment: Sheesh!  My 3 mths of JavaScript [in]experience is showing. Thank you.